# i want to pop up my own dialog(which save file on server without asking the target path location) instead of adobe's save as dialog

Tags: .net, c++, c, visual-c++

Can we override the `Save As` dialog of Adobe Photoshop? How we can override? What will be your approach?

Actually I want to pop up my own dialog (which save file on server without asking the target path location) instead of Adobe's `Save As` dialog.

Answer (score 1):

No, you can't do that. Why do you need this? If you are using the SDK, then you should be able to use the 'Action' objects to save a file to anywhere you want.

Answer (score 1):

Unless there is a plugin API for photoshop that allows that, then you will have to inject some code in the Photoshop process and hook the save as function. Not exactly an easy feat.

Answer (score 1):

As @Nick Whaley suggested you can hook the process, but you don't have to go crazy looking for specific windows.  You don't have to do that at all.  Instead of going the windows route, you can hook CreateFile API, create a custom Action somewhere that would attempt to save a file in a predefined (possibly non-exitent) location. In your hook function look for CreateFile calls where with that special path/name of the file, and display your own save dialog.  Call real open file with desired path, and return a handle to PS.

You will need:
  - MS Detours Express
  - About 2 hours of time

PS. Assign a hot-key to custom PS action, and use it to save files.

Answer (score 1):

@Nick Whaley is right. I don't think the way of @UselessAdmin works because the requirement is popping up another "Save As" dialog, CreateFile is called only after the user chooses a folder and clicks OK in folder dialog, obviously hooking CreateFile is too late.